# How do I trap NumberFormatException thrown by parseInt

Tags: java, parseint, numberformatexception

I am stuck on this question~:

**The method Integer.parseInt converts a String of digits to the int number it denotes.**

```
public static int parseInt (String s)
             throws NumberFormatException
```

**Explain how you could trap the exception thrown by parseInt and illustrate your answer with a code example.**

My answer that I have thought of so far is:

```
try
{
   System.out.println("incorrect");

}

catch (NumberFormatException n)
{
   System.out.println("WRONG! This is not a number");
}
```

I have a feeling this answer is wrong because the code above would only be used in the main method and I'm not sure how I would trap the exception under:

```
public static int parseInt (String s)
             throws NumberFormatException.
```

I've looked through java API for the parseInt method and looked via various research and tried doing the code, however I'm still struggling to get this right due to my lack of understanding.

If anyone could help me out, I'd be grateful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String numStr = "15A";
try {
  int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // not a number
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this is homework, I'll just give you a hint: you have to *call* the method, and surround the call with an appropriate `try`-`catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple,

- in the try block you try to do something. So you try to parse the value of a string into a number. In the try block you can write as many statements as you want.
- When this doesn't work correctly you have the catch block where you can react to certain exceptions that occured (e.g. you tell the user that something went wrong)
- Additionally there is a finally block, which is executed always, no difference if an exception occured or not

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Trapping (in Java it's called catching) an exception happens not inside the method that throws it (`parseInt` in your example), but at the place it is being called. So your example will be just fine when you add `Integer.parseInt(someString)` inside your try-block.